# vb.net dll not loaded

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, gdal

I've made an VB.net app that use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) Dlls to perform geographic stuff.

It runs well on my computer and most users computers, but some users experience problems with the app, and it seems to be an issue with Dll not found.

The log file of my app show this error:

> Unable to load DLL 'ogr_wrap': the specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The Dll ogr_wrap.dll is bundle with the app and is referenced.

I compared dll loaded by the app with Procesxp and it shows that only 3 dlls out of 34 are loaded on the computer where the app doesn't work.

How can it be possible that Dlls are not loaded the same way on different computers ?

Comment: Different OS bitness? Permissions? (obviously differences in path?)

Comment: @Steve All computers are under XP 32 bits, but the app works well on Win 7 64 bits as well. Regarding permissions, users who have the problem are Administrators so I think it's not the issue.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by testing my app on a Windows XP virtual machine with nothing installed and found that a DLL was missing in the dependencies of Gdal.